# Complete classification of lower kinematic pairs

Tags: mechanisms, kinematics

During research I keep seeing the statement saying that all possible lower kinematic pairs can be classified into one of 6 types, those being:

1. Revolute
2. Prismatic
3. Screw
4. Cylindric
5. Spheric
6. Planar

While the statement seems resonable how can we be sure that these 6 pairs are a complete classification of lower kinematic pairs? How can we know no other possibilities exist?

Comment: Doesn't it come from definition of "lower" and "higher" kinematic pairs? "Lower" could simply be these 6 "by definition".